# FQL get post information from post id using stream table

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a post id and I want to run an FQL query to get information about it. The logical query, I thought would be

```sql
SELECT comment_info,
       like_info,
       created_time,
       attachment etc.. 
FROM   stream
WHERE  post_id = thepost_id
```

However this doesn't seem to work (it returns nothing).

I could use a graph api call for this, but it gives some information I don't need and doesn't have some that I do need. This means I have to use multiple graph api calls which is slower and inefficient. I'd rather get the information using FQL where I can specify the specific things I want, but how do I do it?

Additionally, why can't I make a query using the full post id (authorId_postid)? Why do I have to trim off the authorid?

Comment: Well, Stream contains the data which is being shown by your Facebook Home Section. 

This section auto updates based on the priority (EdgeRank Values of the post), hence the same stuff is reflected in the stream table. You can pull out content from either 'Photo' or 'Status' table based upon the data_type you recieve for the post (If it is a status then check for this in status table, else in photos table, or if it is linked to a checkin then go for checkin table). You can always check this reference for FQL - 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql'

Answer (score 0):

To get the comment info, you need to use this fql query:

```
SELECT id, text, time, fromid, is_private, likes, user_likes, parent_id, post_fbid, post_id, comment_count, attachment.media.image.src
FROM comment
WHERE post_id = "787325994631959_790713440959881" //YOUR POST_ID
```

Hope this can help to solve your problem. It works for me.